# Setting Huey to use Redis with Flask

Tags: python, redis, python-huey

[image]

I'm experimenting with the use of Huey as a cross platform task queue . I've found https://github.com/pjcunningham/flask-huey-example , which I've cloned and set up a virtualenv for using conda. (I'm working on windows) following the readme I tried:

```
$ python run_app.py
```

when I open http://localhost:6060/

[image]

I can click on the send button and I see the screenshot. But Although a list is created in REDIS, no task is stored:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "huey.redis."
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange huey.redis -100 100
(empty list or set)
```

How Can I send tasks to the REDIS task queue  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the [Readme](https://github.com/pjcunningham/flask-huey-example/blob/master/readme.md) with instructions on how to run Example 1.

As well as running the Flask app you need to start the [Huey task consumer](https://huey.readthedocs.io/en/latest/consumer.html) and start the dummy SMTP server before you click on the Send button.

Note the parameter passed when starting the Huey consumer (Step 2 in the readme):

```
(flask-huey-example) python d:\Paul\.virtualenv\flask-huey-example\Scripts\huey_consumer.py run_huey.huey
```

The parameter is the dotted path to the `huey` object instance created in the Python script `run_huey.py`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a follow up at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709854/oserror-winerror-10013-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbid