# How to fix ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] the target machine actively refused it? (Django e.mails)

Tags: python, django, sockets, email

I am using Django to send e-mails. I am getting a common network error apparently, but not any of the answers I've read solved. I have a problem with the socket I believe,

When I send the e-mail I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Jaime\Miniconda3\envs\mydjango\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 291, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "C:\Users\Jaime\Miniconda3\envs\mydjango\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
File "C:\Users\Jaime\Miniconda3\envs\mydjango\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 63, in open
self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, 
**connection_params)
File "C:\Users\Jaime\Miniconda3\envs\mydjango\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, 
in __init__
(code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Users\Jaime\Miniconda3\envs\mydjango\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, 
in connect
self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
File "C:\Users\Jaime\Miniconda3\envs\mydjango\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, 
in _get_socket
self.source_address)
File "C:\Users\Jaime\Miniconda3\envs\mydjango\lib\socket.py", line 727, 
in create_connection
raise err
File "C:\Users\Jaime\Miniconda3\envs\mydjango\lib\socket.py", line 716, 
in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made 
because 
the target machine actively refused it
```

Here is what I've tried:

1.
import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com', 80)
socket.getaddrinfo('smtp.hotmail.com', 8000)
socket.getaddrinfo('smtp.hotmail.com', 587)

2. Turn off Firewall / Antivirus
3. Run the code in python shell and in Django app
4. I've got the smtp server out of a nslookup MX query

**I am running this test code in the python shell:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
settings.configure()

from django.core.mail import send_mail

import socket
socket.getaddrinfo('hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com', 80)

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'hotmail-com.olc.protection.outlook.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*******@hotmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '******'
EMAIL_PORT = 587

mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            

to_email = "******@hotmail"
email = EmailMessage(
    mail_subject, "hello", to=[to_email]
)
email.send()
```

**Expected Result:**

For now I want to send e-mails from localhost Django app.
In the future I will upload the code to pythonanywhere.com server.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my Django code to send e-mails:

1. I was missing configurations in settings.py

   **settings.py:**

   ```
   DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'admin@********.com'
   SERVER_EMAIL = 'admin@********.com'
   EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
   EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.********.com'
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'admin@********.com'
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******'
   EMAIL_PORT = 587
   ```
2. Windows configurations

   It had nothing to do with:

   - Firewall
   - Antivirus
3. I was not sure about the name of the SMTP server

   - Make sure you have the correct credentials in `settings.py`
   - My hotmail didn't work in the end. I had to use an e.mail provided by host services.
4. Python shell is different than Django shell
   I was testing the code in python shell.
   The correct thing to do was to call:

   ```
   python manage.py shell
   ```

   instead of just `python`

**Sending the e.mail** (After you have your settings.py file configured):

you can either open the Django shell and copy the code or write in the Django
`views.py` file a specific view

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

mail_subject = 'Active a sua conta.'
message = "message"
to_email = "jaimedcsilva@hotmail.com"

email = EmailMessage(
    mail_subject, message,to=[to_email]
)
email.send()
```

**Worth mentioning:**

- Does not work with port 465
- E.mail sometimes goes to junk folder

Answer (score 0):

The `EMAIL_*` values need to be in your settings module, not in your script. Without those values, the `EmailBackend` class that handles sending the message defaults to trying to connect to `localhost:25`. Since you're not running an SMTP server on your local system, it's refusing the connection.

You don't need the `EMAIL_BACKEND` value because it's the default, but move the other `EMAIL_*` values into your settings module.

Comment: I moved the EMAIL_* values to settings.py in the Django project.

I tried the EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

the e.mail is sent successfully to cmd.

I also tried with EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
and without,

and in both cases I get a similar but different error message:

[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: That sounds like progress! Have you made sure you can actually send mail via this SMTP server?

Comment: I have some more updates. As I was not actually sure about the previous SMTP server, I changed it to another,
that I've used previously for the same purpose, but with PHP.
The recommendation is to use port 465, it takes about 2 minutes untill I get the error:
in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
I also tried port 587, I get almost immediatly the following errror:
in sendmail
    raise SMTPDataError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPDataError: (550, b'"Message rejected by local rules"')

Comment: This is starting to sound like a different question! And I'm not sure what more to suggest. I'd recommend updating your question with your current code and error messages, or asking a new one.

Comment: yes! I think it is better to create a new post. I ended up moving from python shell to Django again. I think I'm getting closer to get this working. just got another email from hostgator, testing it right now.
Thanks

Comment: Does all this(win 10061 Error in Django) will depend on the OS we are using. Because In Linux I am not facing the issue but with Windows I am facing. Please suggest me.